# AWS Docker image not being pulled completely

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a custom tomcat docker image where we add the setenv.sh while building the image.
After updating the setenv.sh recently and redeploying, the change is not being seen in AWS, but if I docker pull the created image locally the change is present.

Is there any reason why this could be happening?

```
FROM tomcat:7.0-jdk8
...
# Copy Application
COPY ./platform-war/ ./platform-war/
COPY ./scripts/ ./scripts/ 
...
# Tomcat additional env
RUN /bin/bash -c "ln -s $BASE_DIR/scripts/setenv.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh"
# Make sripts executable
RUN /bin/bash -c "chmod -R +x $BASE_DIR/scripts"
```

And inside the image in aws the link is working as expected

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1975 Jul  2  2021 digest.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3718 Jul  2  2021 setclasspath.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     32 Feb  3 23:15 setenv.sh -> /opt/base/scripts/setenv.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1912 Jul  2  2021 shutdown.sh
```

yet, the content of the setenv is not the expected one, it is an old one.
The image looks updated cause it has present code changes.

Comment: How are you creating and deploying the image?

Comment: The image is created in jenkins and pushed into artifactory. In aws, we update the version and that triggers a pull